# Parsing query string in OpenCMS

Tags: jsp, query-string, opencms

I need to parse a query string.  The page is a jsp in OpenCMS.  Tag libraries we typically load are c, cms, x, fn.  How can I parse a query string with one of these (or another) tag library?

Comment: If its a JSP, then use request.getParameter, right? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

For example you can retrieve parameter 'p' with jstl in this way:

```
<c:out value="${param.p}" />
```

Comment: Thank you both.  It can be surprising how something simple can elude even a determined Google search.  I finally threw this up on SO because I didn't want to waste any more time looking and had other tasks to work on.  Needing to do something simple in a language you don't know can be just as hard as...well, something hard.  Thanks again!